# node's q.fcall returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, q

In the node shell I see this:

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(Q.fcall(function() { return 10 })));
{}
undefined
```

HOwever the docs for q here :[Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)
say that it returns a promise, which is an object with an apply() and a then() function.

So why is this returning an empty object??

Comment: Why are you stringifying it? Just log the actual object that Q.fcall returns, it should be a promise.

Answer (score 1):

> So why is this returning an empty object??

Because [JSON](http://json.org/) cannot represent function objects, and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will ignore any function properties.

Instead, don't use `JSON.stringify` at all - just directly `console.log(Q.fcall(function() { return 10 }))` and inspect the logged value. Btw, you there's no need to use `fcall` with a constant function, simply go with the [`Q` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue): `console.log(Q(10))`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be based on the timing of the `JSON.stringify` function.  For instance:

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(Q.fcall(function() { return 10; })));
'{}'
> var p = Q.fcall(function() { return 10; });
> console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
'{"source":{}}'
```

And using it as a promise:

```
> p.then(function(value) { console.log(value); });
10
```